# getting UUIDs from G- Shock watch bluetooth android

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on Bluetooth Low Energy in Android. I want to get the `UUIDs` of remote device when the device is paired. I have found that `BluetoothDevice.getUuids()` will give the `UUIDs` of a remote device. I have used that in the settings application of **ICS**. I am able to get the `UUIDs` of classic device and dongle which is a Low energy device. But I am not able to get the `UUIDs` of a **casio watch** which is also a low energy.

Can you please help me on this issue?

Comment: I don't recall BLE being supported across the board in Android. What Android device are you using for your testing?

Comment: I am using a qualcomm software in android to get the BLE support to the device

Comment: Which Android device are you working with?

Answer (score 2):

`BluetoothDevice.getUuids()` This method does not start a service discovery procedure to retrieve the UUIDs from the remote device. Instead, the local cached copy of the service UUIDs are returned.

Use `fetchUuidsWithSdp()` if fresh UUIDs are desired. 
May this helps